# Returning only rows with unique value in specific column (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, connected_tracks FROM track_nodes;
```

Which returns the following rows:

```
1 "1100 1100 1200"
2 "1100 1100 1300"
3 "1100 1100 1300"
4 "1100 1200 1400"
```

How can I modify my query, so that I only return rows that are not duplicated ?

Using the above example, I would only wish to return these rows:

```
1 "1100 1100 1200"
4 "1100 1200 1400"
```

The important point is that I don't want ANY of the duplicated rows.

I am using Postgres 9.3.

Whenever I search for ways to do this, I find many, many references to using "DISTINCT". But as far as I can tell, this won't give the answer I want - I think it would also give me one row where the "connected_track" value is duplicated.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to do this ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Distinct *is* the answer, but there aren't any duplicated **rows** in your example at all.

Comment: OK, I guess I mean distinct values on a column, rather than rows - my mistake.

Comment: Then still, you would want to return 1, 2 & 4 *or* 1, 3 & 4. Not 1 & 4 only.

Comment: No, I just want 1 and 4. I don't want any rows that have a value in column "connected_tracks" that occurs more than once. Sorry if I'm not explaining too clearly :)

Comment: Ok, i get it now, then words like *unique* is misleading.

Comment: Yes I realise that now :) Have edited the title, hopefully slightly less misleading.

Comment: The query has 2 columns, the result has 3. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **remove** any rows, in which `connected_tracks` occurs more than once per the table, you need to do a self anti-join:

```
   SELECT t.id, t.connected_tracks
     FROM track_nodes AS t
LEFT JOIN track_nodes AS j
       ON t.connected_tracks = j.connected_tracks
      AND t.id <> j.id
    WHERE j.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, just the job.

Comment: I also found this to work:

    SELECT id, connected_tracks
    FROM track_nodes as tn
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track_nodes WHERE connected_tracks= tn.connected_tracks) < 2

Maybe not as elegant as the solution above though.

Comment: Also that cannot be optimised by Posgres properly, i think. There is also a `NOT EXISTS` variant, but Posgres clever enough to transform it to its anti-join variant under the hood, that's why i left out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id),
       connected_tracks
from track_nodes
group by connected_tracks
having count(*) = 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3227e/1

Could potentially be faster than a self-join